# При изменении csv файла ошибка "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, datetime

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой в python3.10.4 :

Задача - изменить в csv файле формат даты с `дд.мм.гг` на `гг-мм-дд` (изменить порядок значений и разделитель заменить с точки на тире).
Сам код:

```
import datetime

with open("data/btc_usd_2015.csv", 'r') as csvfile, open('data/temp.csv', 'w') as temp_file:

    for lines in csvfile.readlines():
        # Fetch all dates in the csv
        dates = lines

        # Extract date, month and year
        dt, mon, yr = dates[1].split(',')

        # Convert the date 
        dates[1] = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates[1], '%d.%b.%y').strftime('%y-%b-%d')

        # Write date to temp file
        temp_file.write(','.join(dates))

print("Process complete!")
```

После запуска выдает следующую ошибку:

```
   line 10, in <module>
    dt, mon, yr = dates[1].split(',')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Уже разные варианты перепробовал - все равно эта ошибка (также прикрепляю **скрин с форматированием csv файла с исходными данными**).

Огромное спасибо за помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то такое наверное всё-таки: `dt, mon, yr = lines.split(',')[0].split('.')`, зависит от того, где у вас там дата, на какой позиции

Comment: А вообще лучше изучите `Pandas`, им гораздо проще `csv` файлы читать и работать с ними.

Comment: Так то у вас дальнейший код похоже предполагает, что `dates = lines.split(',')`, а не то, что у вас написано. И в этом случае `dt, mon, yr = dates[0].split('.')`, но опять же вы эти переменные `dt, mon, yr` дальше не используете. Сначала поймите, что у вас в переменных. Напечатайте что у вас в `dates`, это всегда полезно.

Answer (score 1):

`dates[1]` не несёт нужного смысла. Правильно - `dt, mon, yr = dates.split(',')`
Тогда получите следующую ошибку:-)

А вообще - читайте тексты ошибок и анализируйте их. Вам писали - "1 значение получено, а ждут 3". Так распечатайте ваш `dates[1]` и сразу увидите, что он - не то, что вы ждали, а только часть (цифра 1 - треть триплета ожидаемого)  - значит, всё вместе есть в полном `dates`.

Но вопрос вы задали качественно, да. С ним всё понятно, где искать и как воспроизводить. Это +1 за вопрос :-)

Comment: Всё же это больше тянет на комментарий, а не на ответ )

Comment: Наверное так и есть, просто не помещается всё в коммент + уверен, что расширится вопрос.